# Регистрация хендлеров aiogram 2

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет, прошу помощи, не могу найти нужно информации.
Суть такова.
Имеется 2 файла - file1.py, file2.py

Первый файл - главный,основной

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    )

    dp.register_message_handler(callback=start_bot_message, commands=['start'], chat_type="private")
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(cancel_handler, lambda callback_query == "wgfergeg")

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

В нем я пытаюсь зарегистрировать хендрер, который находится в файле file2.py.
Тоесть при нажатии на инлайн кнопку, хочу запускать нужную функцию.

```
dp.register_callback_query_handler(cancel_handler, lambda callback_query == "wgfergeg")
```

Но не понимаю что делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

В register_callback_query_handler стоит использовать не callback_query, а callback.data

```py
dp.register_callback_query_handler(cancel_handler, lambda callback: callback.data == "wgfergeg")
```

Comment: Как вариант, вместо анонимной функции можно использовать просто фильтр text

dp.register_callback_query_handler(cancel_handler, text="wgfergeg")

Comment: Огромное спасибо, это то что мне было нужно!)